# GROUP BY vs INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql

Hi!
I need to scan a very large table on mysql (5.1), 
this is how the table looks like more or less:

```
 CREATE TABLE `big_table` (
   `id` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `main_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `key` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `main_id_key` (`main_id`,`key`),
 ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=2315678197 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to get all unique values of main_id + keys into a new table.
Using the following query takes a lot of time (still running after 3 days on a very fast server):

```
 CREATE TABLE `get_unique` (
   `main_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `key` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`main_id`,`key`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INSERT IGNORE INTO get_unique 
 SELECT main_id,key FROM big_table
```

**So my question is - 
Will this be faster?**

```
 CREATE TABLE `get_unique` (
   `main_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `key` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`main_id`,`key`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INSERT INTO get_unique 
 SELECT main_id,key FROM big_table
 GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Results: INSERT IGNORE was running for over 47 hours before it was killed. INSERT as SELECT ... GROUP BY finished running after 15 hours.

Comment: If your goal was to get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column `\`id\`` in favor of the `\`main_id_key\`` index, and removing the duplicate rows then you could just have used `ALTER IGNORE TABLE \`big_table\` ADD UNIQUE (\`main_id\`, \`key\`)`. No need for a temporary table like `\`get_unique\``.  

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `GROUP BY main_id, key` will perform many times faster as compared to `INSERT IGNORE`.

`SELECT.. GROUP BY main_id, key` would get executed faster by making use of covering index and result in a fewer number of records, whereas `INSERT IGNORE` will involve `INDEX KEY` look-ups for every row that is being inserted.